# Trigger : insert a row just inserted

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-workbench

I would like to create a trigger which permits me to insert in another table a column that I have just inserted. I follow some advices on the forum and so this is my trigger creation :

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `database`.`Action_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `Action` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO `database`.`StockConnu` (`Action_Isin`)
SELECT `Isin` FROM `inserted`;END;
```

To insert, my request :

```
INSERT INTO `database`.`action`
(`Isin`,
`Valeur`,
`Maj`,
`Devise`)
VALUES
('YHOO',
34,
'2015-02-07',
'euro');
```

Workbench tells me :

```
Error Code: 1146. Table 'database.inserted' doesn't exist
```

I tried without quote and other syntax but it still doesn't work when I insert a data in Action.

Please help...

EDIT :

Problem solved with the "new." trick exposed below by zsuzsa-matyas

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the following line:

```
 SELECT Isin FROM inserted;
```

The database name should be specified as in the other INSERT command:

```
SELECT NEW.Isin;
```

Comment: Is the error message the same as before? I don't have much experience on triggers, because it is not recommended to use them for many reasons - so in case you have a choice to use it or not, i would recommend to solve this without a trigger (for example i would create a stored procedure for solving this task, which runs once per hour/day)

Comment: The same yes. For the moment, I'm doing as you're saying to continue. But it's the first time, I find nothing on the weeb to solve it :(

Comment: I think the inserted item can be referenced like this: SELECT NEW.Isin; and the FROM clause is not needed (still not sure and I can't check it on my own DB right now - let me know whether this statement works)

Comment: Good to hear that it works, I wasn't sure about it and couldn't check it :)